Haproxy not logging from LUA core.log()
I'm encountering an issue with HAProxy configuration where the logs from the LUA core.register_action and core.register_service scripts aren't being recorded in the expected log files.
The logs from core.Info(ip) are being logged in /var/log/messages, but I need them in /var/log/haproxy.log.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
core.register_action("verify_request", { "http-req" }, function(txn)
    ....
    txn:Info(ip) -- this got logged into /var/log/haproxy
end)

core.register_service("send_response", "http", function(applet)
    ....    
    core.Info(ip) -- this got logged into /var/log/messages
end)

HAProxy configuration (haproxy.cfg):
log global 
option httplog
option dontlognull
option dontlog-normal
log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug

Rsyslog configuration (rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf):
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514

local0.*        /var/log/haproxy.log

Is there a specific configuration I might be missing that would direct all logs from both the Lua actions to the same log file?

As a work around, adding this to rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf works: if $programname == 'haproxy' then /var/log/haproxy.log  & ~
